# Qt plugin does not handle class with same name and different folders/namespaces

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013, qtplugin

I'm creating in Visual Studio a Qt project with the Qt plugin version 1.2.4.

This is my folder structure:

```
 src\
 |
 |-Class.h      -- It defines Class
 |-Class.cpp
 |
 |-Private\
   |-Class.h    -- It defines Private::Class
   |-Class.cpp
```

In `src/Class.h` I use the pimpl idion in order to use Private::Class and putting here logic.

Both `Class` and `Private::Class` are qobjects, so I declare `Q_OBJECT` in both headers. But the plugin creates only one moc header. It creates `moc_Class.cpp` in both cases and mocs overwrite each other.

I there a way to handle with the qt plugin different classes in different folders and namespace but with the same name, or I must be forced to use unique names for all classes of my project?